# How to calculate confirmatory factor analysis by hand?

Tags: estimation, confirmatory-factor

I am trying to learn how confirmatory factor analysis works and the way I learn is best by understanding how the calculations work by hand using a pen, paper, and a calculator, and then replicate this calculation manually in R. I'm also trying to learn to understand formula notation. Particularly, I looking for guidance on how to calculate

1. Factor scores and factor loadings
2. Model fit indices: Chi sq., RMSEA, CFI, TLI, SRMR

Through this process, I want to answer other questions such as:

- Why are factor loadings set at 1?
- How to use values from a CFA in a measurement model with a path analysis model using latent variables?

Here is example data from the `HolzingerSwineford1939` dataset from the `lavaan` package. I selected a few variables: `id, school, x1 - x9`

```
dput(ex_data)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 38L, 39L, 
40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 
54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 60L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 
69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 
82L, 83L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 
97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 108L, 
109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 
120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 
132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 142L, 143L, 
144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 
155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 
167L, 168L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 
211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 
222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 
233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 
244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 
256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 
267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 
278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 
289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 
300L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 
312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 320L, 321L, 322L, 323L, 
324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 330L, 331L, 333L, 334L, 335L, 
336L, 337L, 338L, 339L, 340L, 341L, 342L, 343L, 344L, 345L, 346L, 
347L, 348L, 349L, 351L), school = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Grant-White", 
"Pasteur"), class = "factor"), x1 = c(3.3333333, 5.3333333, 4.5, 
5.3333333, 4.8333333, 5.3333333, 2.8333333, 5.6666667, 4.5, 3.5, 
3.6666667, 5.8333333, 5.6666667, 6, 5.8333333, 4.6666667, 4.3333333, 
5, 5.6666667, 6.3333333, 5.8333333, 6.6666667, 5, 3.8333333, 
5.6666667, 5.3333333, 5.5, 6, 4.6666667, 5, 3.5, 3, 5, 4.1666667, 
3.3333333, 4.8333333, 5.5, 3.8333333, 6.3333333, 5.8333333, 3.8333333, 
3.1666667, 1.8333333, 4.1666667, 6.3333333, 6, 7.1666667, 3.1666667, 
4.3333333, 4.5, 5.5, 7, 3.8333333, 5.1666667, 5, 5.6666667, 4, 
5.8333333, 3.8333333, 4.1666667, 5.3333333, 4, 5.3333333, 5.3333333, 
3.6666667, 6.5, 4, 4.6666667, 2.8333333, 4.6666667, 0.66666667, 
4.3333333, 5, 5, 4.1666667, 3.8333333, 5.6666667, 1.6666667, 
6.3333333, 4, 4.5, 4.6666667, 4.8333333, 4.8333333, 3, 6.3333333, 
5.5, 5.3333333, 3.3333333, 5.5, 4, 3.8333333, 5.1666667, 4.3333333, 
4.1666667, 5, 4.3333333, 7.5, 5, 5.5, 6.1666667, 6.5, 4.3333333, 
4.6666667, 6.8333333, 4.5, 6.8333333, 5.5, 6.3333333, 4.1666667, 
5.6666667, 6.3333333, 6.1666667, 5.1666667, 4.1666667, 4.1666667, 
5.1666667, 4.3333333, 3.5, 4.6666667, 4.8333333, 5, 7.5, 5.3333333, 
6.1666667, 5.3333333, 4.3333333, 4.8333333, 6, 5, 4.1666667, 
5.6666667, 5, 3.5, 7.3333333, 6.1666667, 4.8333333, 5.6666667, 
5.5, 5.1666667, 3.1666667, 5, 7.1666667, 7.3333333, 2, 3.8333333, 
4.1666667, 4.6666667, 5.8333333, 6.6666667, 6.8333333, 5.3333333, 
4.8333333, 5.1666667, 6.3333333, 4.8333333, 3.8333333, 5.5, 5.6666667, 
4.8333333, 2.6666667, 5, 6, 4.6666667, 5, 3.3333333, 4.5, 5.3333333, 
6.3333333, 2.8333333, 5.6666667, 4.1666667, 5.5, 6.6666667, 5, 
6, 4, 6.6666667, 5, 7, 5.5, 5.3333333, 5.1666667, 4.5, 5.1666667, 
5.1666667, 2.8333333, 5, 4.6666667, 3.1666667, 4.6666667, 6.3333333, 
5.6666667, 3, 2.6666667, 3, 5.3333333, 5.6666667, 3.5, 4.6666667, 
6.5, 5.3333333, 4.6666667, 4, 5.1666667, 4.8333333, 4.8333333, 
2.6666667, 4.1666667, 4.1666667, 6.1666667, 5, 4.8333333, 6.1666667, 
4.6666667, 3.6666667, 6.3333333, 4.8333333, 4.1666667, 4.6666667, 
3.8333333, 1.8333333, 7.5, 3.1666667, 6.8333333, 5.8333333, 5.6666667, 
3.1666667, 4.1666667, 6, 3.1666667, 4.5, 3.5, 4.5, 4.3333333, 
3.3333333, 5.5, 6.3333333, 5.5, 6, 6.3333333, 5.1666667, 6, 5.1666667, 
4.6666667, 6.3333333, 4.8333333, 5.8333333, 5.8333333, 3.8333333, 
5.1666667, 8.5, 5.5, 3.5, 6.1666667, 6.1666667, 6.1666667, 6.5, 
6.5, 3, 4.6666667, 4.8333333, 4.1666667, 4.8333333, 5.3333333, 
5, 5.8333333, 2.6666667, 6.3333333, 4.3333333, 5.5, 4.6666667, 
4.5, 4.3333333, 5, 3.6666667, 5.3333333, 5.1666667, 5.3333333, 
6.6666667, 3.5, 5.1666667, 4, 6.8333333, 5, 5.8333333, 5.6666667, 
4.1666667, 4, 6, 3.3333333, 4.6666667, 5.6666667, 5.6666667, 
5.8333333, 6.1666667, 4, 3, 4.6666667, 4.3333333, 4.3333333), 
    x2 = c(7.75, 5.25, 5.25, 7.75, 4.75, 5, 6, 6.25, 5.75, 5.25, 
    5.75, 6, 4.5, 5.5, 5.75, 4.75, 4.75, 6.75, 5.25, 8.75, 8, 
    8.5, 6.25, 5.5, 5.5, 4, 5.25, 5, 6, 4.5, 5.75, 6, 5.25, 6, 
    3.75, 5.25, 7, 4.5, 4, 7.75, 5.75, 5, 5.25, 5.25, 5.5, 5.5, 
    8.5, 4.75, 5.5, 6.25, 5.75, 6, 7.5, 4.75, 6, 5.25, 4.75, 
    5.25, 6.5, 5.75, 5.75, 6, 6.75, 5, 5.75, 6, 9.25, 5.75, 5, 
    5, 4.5, 9.25, 4.5, 6, 5.25, 5.25, 7, 5.75, 5.5, 5.25, 6, 
    8, 8.25, 6.5, 5.25, 6.25, 7, 6, 7.25, 5, 6.5, 6.25, 4.75, 
    3.5, 5.5, 5.75, 4.75, 7.5, 3.75, 6.25, 3.75, 6.5, 7.75, 5.25, 
    9, 6.5, 6.5, 6.75, 5.5, 4.25, 9.25, 5.25, 6.25, 6.5, 7.5, 
    5.75, 5.75, 5.25, 7.25, 4.75, 6, 5.5, 7, 5.25, 6.75, 8.75, 
    7, 7, 7.5, 4.5, 8, 5.5, 6.25, 5.25, 8, 7.5, 5.25, 6.25, 6.75, 
    5, 3.75, 7.5, 9, 6.75, 5.5, 5.5, 6, 5.75, 4.75, 5.5, 7.25, 
    4.75, 5, 6, 6.75, 5.75, 4.75, 5.5, 6, 5.75, 6.25, 6.25, 8.25, 
    6.25, 6.25, 6.25, 6.5, 5.25, 7.75, 5.25, 7, 7.75, 7.75, 5.75, 
    5.5, 7, 4, 6.5, 6, 6.75, 6.75, 5.5, 5.25, 5.75, 5.75, 8.5, 
    7.5, 5, 4.75, 5.5, 5, 6.25, 7, 5.5, 5, 7.5, 5.25, 5.25, 5.5, 
    5, 6, 6.5, 6, 5, 4.75, 6.5, 7.5, 5.75, 6.25, 6.75, 7.75, 
    6.5, 6, 8.5, 5, 8.5, 5.25, 5.25, 6.25, 6.75, 5, 5, 9.25, 
    3.75, 5.25, 7.5, 6, 5.5, 5.25, 7, 5.75, 5.25, 2.25, 5.5, 
    5.5, 6.75, 5.5, 6.5, 6.25, 7.25, 7.25, 6.25, 7, 6.5, 6, 9.25, 
    8.5, 6, 6.25, 5.25, 7, 6.5, 7, 6.5, 8, 5, 6.5, 6.5, 8.5, 
    4, 7, 5.75, 5, 8.25, 5.25, 5.25, 7, 8.5, 7.5, 6.25, 7, 6.75, 
    5.5, 7.25, 8, 5.75, 6, 5.75, 6.25, 5.25, 5, 6.25, 6, 6.25, 
    5.75, 5, 6.75, 5.5, 6.25, 6.5, 4.75, 6, 5.5, 5.25, 7, 6.5, 
    7, 6, 5.5, 6.75, 6), x3 = c(0.375, 2.125, 1.875, 3, 0.875, 
    2.25, 1, 1.875, 1.5, 0.75, 2, 2.875, 4.125, 1.75, 3.625, 
    2.375, 1.5, 2.25, 4, 3, 2, 4.125, 1.875, 1.625, 1.25, 3.375, 
    4.5, 2.125, 4.25, 0.75, 1.375, 0.25, 1.75, 2.375, 1.5, 0.5, 
    3.5, 2.25, 3.875, 2.5, 1.625, 1.25, 1, 1.875, 2.75, 4.5, 
    4, 1.375, 2.75, 1.125, 3.75, 2.125, 3.25, 1.75, 4.125, 2.125, 
    3.25, 3.875, 2, 1.75, 3.375, 3.625, 1.375, 1.25, 3.625, 2.5, 
    4, 3.625, 0.875, 0.75, 0.75, 3.375, 2.625, 3.25, 2.125, 2.375, 
    2.125, 1.375, 4.125, 2.5, 1.75, 4.25, 2.25, 1.75, 0.625, 
    2.5, 2.875, 2.75, 3.25, 2.25, 2.625, 3.375, 2.125, 0.875, 
    0.875, 4.25, 0.5, 2.125, 1.375, 2.75, 4.375, 1.875, 1.875, 
    1.625, 4.375, 3.125, 0.75, 3.75, 1.625, 2.25, 4.375, 2.625, 
    4.25, 1.75, 3.875, 1, 2.5, 4, 3.375, 1.625, 1.5, 2.375, 4.25, 
    4.125, 4.125, 3.125, 1, 1.125, 3.25, 1.625, 4.375, 3.5, 1.75, 
    2.25, 2.625, 3.625, 4.5, 2.75, 4.5, 2.5, 1.5, 4.5, 3.875, 
    4, 0.625, 1.875, 1.25, 1.625, 2.625, 4.375, 4.25, 2.625, 
    2.375, 2.375, 1.125, 1.25, 0.5, 2.125, 2.75, 1.125, 1.25, 
    2.5, 4.5, 1.125, 1.375, 0.75, 0.75, 1, 1.5, 0.75, 3, 2.25, 
    3.75, 2.5, 2.5, 2.75, 1.75, 3.25, 2.375, 3.375, 2, 1.875, 
    0.625, 0.5, 1.375, 0.375, 1.625, 1.625, 1, 1, 1.75, 1.625, 
    1.25, 0.625, 1, 2.125, 1.125, 1.125, 1, 1.75, 3.125, 1.25, 
    1, 2.75, 1.625, 3.125, 1.875, 0.625, 3.25, 1.875, 2, 2.375, 
    1.25, 2.125, 0.5, 2.375, 2.25, 2.25, 3.75, 1.625, 2.25, 1.125, 
    3.625, 0.875, 1.375, 4.125, 2, 1.5, 1.875, 4.125, 0.75, 0.875, 
    1.75, 4, 1, 1.875, 1.75, 0.875, 4.25, 2, 4.375, 3.5, 1.625, 
    3.625, 0.75, 3.5, 2.75, 1.875, 3.125, 0.375, 3.125, 4.25, 
    2.25, 2.125, 1.375, 2.625, 3.625, 3, 4.125, 0.5, 2.25, 1.125, 
    1.375, 1.375, 1.875, 2.625, 2.375, 4, 4.125, 0.875, 1.5, 
    4, 2, 1.25, 3.25, 1, 1, 1.625, 2.125, 1.875, 1.375, 3.25, 
    2, 1.875, 1.25, 2, 2.125, 1.625, 0.75, 2.125, 0.875, 1.125, 
    1.625, 2.375, 1.25, 3, 1.375, 1.625, 1.875, 0.5, 3.375), 
    x4 = c(2.3333333, 1.6666667, 1, 2.6666667, 2.6666667, 1, 
    3.3333333, 3.6666667, 2.6666667, 2.6666667, 2, 2.6666667, 
    2.6666667, 4.6666667, 5, 2.6666667, 2, 2, 4.3333333, 3.6666667, 
    1.6666667, 2, 3.3333333, 2.6666667, 2.3333333, 1.6666667, 
    2.6666667, 1.6666667, 2, 2.6666667, 2, 1.6666667, 2.6666667, 
    3.3333333, 1.3333333, 1.6666667, 2.6666667, 3, 4, 3, 2.6666667, 
    1.6666667, 1.6666667, 2, 4.6666667, 3, 0.66666667, 2.6666667, 
    2, 3.6666667, 1.6666667, 2.3333333, 0.66666667, 3.3333333, 
    2, 2.6666667, 1.6666667, 2.6666667, 1, 1.3333333, 4, 2.6666667, 
    1.6666667, 3.3333333, 2.6666667, 3.6666667, 3, 2.6666667, 
    3, 4.3333333, 2, 1.3333333, 1.6666667, 3.3333333, 3, 1.6666667, 
    4, 0, 4, 1, 1.6666667, 3, 0.33333333, 2.3333333, 1, 3.3333333, 
    2.6666667, 4, 1.3333333, 3.6666667, 2.6666667, 2, 1, 2.6666667, 
    4.6666667, 4, 3.3333333, 5.3333333, 1.6666667, 3.6666667, 
    2.6666667, 3.6666667, 4.3333333, 3.3333333, 2.6666667, 2.6666667, 
    5.3333333, 2.6666667, 5.6666667, 3.3333333, 3.6666667, 4.3333333, 
    5, 4, 1, 3.6666667, 2.6666667, 3, 2.3333333, 2.6666667, 2.6666667, 
    3.3333333, 4, 2.3333333, 3.3333333, 4.3333333, 4.3333333, 
    3.3333333, 3, 2, 4.3333333, 4, 1.3333333, 2, 2.6666667, 4, 
    4.3333333, 3.3333333, 2.3333333, 3.3333333, 3.3333333, 2, 
    3.6666667, 6, 2.6666667, 3.6666667, 4, 0.66666667, 5.6666667, 
    2.6666667, 5, 3, 3, 1.3333333, 3, 3, 3.3333333, 2.6666667, 
    3.6666667, 3, 2.6666667, 3.3333333, 5.6666667, 3.3333333, 
    3.6666667, 3, 3.3333333, 0.33333333, 3.3333333, 1.6666667, 
    4.6666667, 2.3333333, 3.6666667, 3.3333333, 2.6666667, 4.3333333, 
    1.6666667, 4.3333333, 4.6666667, 2.3333333, 2.6666667, 3, 
    4.3333333, 3, 1.3333333, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1.6666667, 2.6666667, 
    3, 3, 0.66666667, 2, 6.3333333, 5, 3, 3, 2.6666667, 4.6666667, 
    3.6666667, 2, 3.6666667, 2.6666667, 3.3333333, 2.3333333, 
    2.3333333, 1.6666667, 2, 4.6666667, 2.3333333, 3, 6, 2.6666667, 
    3.3333333, 6, 2.3333333, 3, 1.6666667, 2, 4.3333333, 3.3333333, 
    5, 3, 2.6666667, 3, 3.3333333, 2.6666667, 5, 2.3333333, 3, 
    5, 2.6666667, 1.6666667, 3, 4.3333333, 5.3333333, 5, 3, 4.3333333, 
    3.3333333, 3.6666667, 3.6666667, 2.6666667, 3.3333333, 3.3333333, 
    4, 3.6666667, 3, 4, 6, 5, 4, 5.3333333, 2.6666667, 2.3333333, 
    5.6666667, 3.3333333, 3.3333333, 3.3333333, 2, 4, 4.3333333, 
    4.6666667, 4, 6, 4.6666667, 4.6666667, 3.3333333, 4.6666667, 
    3.3333333, 2.6666667, 2.6666667, 2.3333333, 1.3333333, 3, 
    4, 1.6666667, 2.6666667, 2.3333333, 5, 2.6666667, 4, 2.6666667, 
    3.3333333, 4.3333333, 2.3333333, 3, 3.3333333, 2.6666667, 
    1.3333333, 3.3333333, 3.3333333, 3, 3, 2.6666667, 2.3333333, 
    3.6666667, 3.6666667, 3.6666667), x5 = c(5.75, 3, 1.75, 4.5, 
    4, 3, 6, 4.25, 5.75, 5, 3.5, 4.5, 4, 4, 5.5, 4.25, 4, 2.5, 
    5.25, 3.75, 2.5, 3.25, 5.75, 3, 3.75, 3.5, 2.25, 3, 3, 3.25, 
    3.5, 3, 5.25, 4.25, 3, 4.75, 4, 3, 5.25, 5.25, 4.25, 4.25, 
    3.75, 3, 5.5, 4.25, 1, 3.25, 2.25, 5.5, 2.25, 4.5, 1.5, 3.5, 
    4.5, 4.5, 3, 5.5, 2.5, 3, 5.5, 5, 2.5, 4.5, 5, 4.5, 3.75, 
    2.75, 2.5, 4, 3, 2.25, 2.75, 5.75, 3.25, 2.25, 4.75, 1.5, 
    3.25, 1.5, 2, 4.75, 2.25, 3.5, 1.5, 5.75, 4, 5, 1.25, 4.5, 
    2.75, 3.75, 2, 3.25, 4.75, 4.25, 5.75, 6.75, 2.75, 4.5, 3.25, 
    3.75, 4.5, 4.5, 5.75, 5.5, 5.75, 2.75, 5.5, 3.5, 4.75, 4.25, 
    3.5, 5.25, 2, 4.75, 4.75, 2.75, 2.25, 3.25, 4.25, 3, 6.5, 
    3.75, 5, 4, 5.5, 5, 6, 2.75, 6.25, 4.25, 2, 3.75, 5, 6.25, 
    5.75, 5.25, 4.5, 5.75, 5.75, 1.5, 5.25, 6.5, 5, 5, 5, 2.5, 
    5.5, 3.75, 5.75, 5.5, 4.25, 2.25, 2.5, 4.75, 4.25, 4.25, 
    4.75, 4.75, 6.25, 5.75, 6.25, 4.5, 5.25, 5.25, 4, 1.75, 2.75, 
    2.5, 5.5, 3, 5.75, 5.75, 4.25, 6, 4.25, 6, 6.5, 3.25, 4.25, 
    5, 4.75, 2.75, 4, 4.75, 4.25, 5, 3.5, 3, 3.75, 5.75, 5.5, 
    1, 4.5, 6, 5, 5.75, 3, 4.5, 4.25, 5.75, 2.5, 4.75, 5.5, 5.5, 
    4, 5, 1.75, 4, 7, 5.25, 5.25, 6, 4.5, 4.25, 6.5, 4, 4, 1.5, 
    3, 4, 4, 4.75, 4, 3.75, 3.5, 4, 4.25, 6, 3.25, 4.75, 6.25, 
    3.25, 2.75, 4.75, 6.25, 6.25, 5.75, 5.75, 5.5, 6.25, 5.75, 
    6.5, 4.25, 4.75, 5, 5, 6, 5.25, 5.75, 6.5, 5.75, 4, 6.25, 
    4.75, 4.75, 6.5, 4.75, 5.25, 6.25, 6, 4.75, 5.75, 5, 6, 6.75, 
    5.5, 5.5, 3.75, 5.25, 4.75, 4.75, 4.75, 3.75, 3.25, 4.75, 
    4.75, 2.75, 4.5, 4.75, 6, 4.5, 5.25, 3.5, 4, 6.25, 4, 4.75, 
    4.75, 5, 3, 4.25, 4.5, 3.25, 4.25, 4.25, 4, 5.75, 4.5, 5.75
    ), x6 = c(1.2857143, 1.2857143, 0.42857143, 2.4285714, 2.5714286, 
    0.85714286, 2.8571429, 1.2857143, 2.7142857, 2.5714286, 1.5714286, 
    2.7142857, 2.2857143, 1.5714286, 3, 0.71428571, 1.2857143, 
    1.7142857, 3.7142857, 2.5714286, 0.57142857, 2.1428571, 3.1428571, 
    1, 1.2857143, 1.4285714, 0.71428571, 1.1428571, 2, 1.8571429, 
    1.8571429, 1, 2, 1.8571429, 0.85714286, 1.4285714, 2, 1.7142857, 
    3.2857143, 3.1428571, 2.1428571, 1.5714286, 0.57142857, 1.4285714, 
    2, 1.2857143, 1, 1.2857143, 1, 2.1428571, 0.14285714, 1.4285714, 
    0.14285714, 2.1428571, 2.1428571, 1.4285714, 1.7142857, 2.4285714, 
    1.2857143, 1, 2.5714286, 2.1428571, 0.71428571, 2.4285714, 
    1.4285714, 3, 1, 1.8571429, 1.5714286, 2.7142857, 1, 1.1428571, 
    1.5714286, 2.7142857, 0.71428571, 1, 2.2857143, 1.1428571, 
    1.8571429, 1.8571429, 1.5714286, 2.4285714, 0.57142857, 0.71428571, 
    1, 3.7142857, 0.85714286, 2.1428571, 0.57142857, 1.7142857, 
    1.8571429, 0.42857143, 1.5714286, 1.1428571, 2.1428571, 2.4285714, 
    2.8571429, 2.7142857, 1.4285714, 3.2857143, 1, 1.7142857, 
    1.8571429, 2.8571429, 5, 2.1428571, 3.1428571, 2, 4, 1.4285714, 
    3, 1.5714286, 1.8571429, 1.8571429, 0.85714286, 1.8571429, 
    2.7142857, 1, 1.1428571, 2, 1.2857143, 2, 3.5714286, 1.5714286, 
    2.8571429, 1.1428571, 3, 2.2857143, 2.4285714, 0.57142857, 
    3.1428571, 2.2857143, 0.57142857, 1.8571429, 2.4285714, 2.5714286, 
    2.8571429, 2.1428571, 2.5714286, 3, 2.2857143, 0.42857143, 
    4.7142857, 6.1428571, 0.85714286, 3, 2.5714286, 1.4285714, 
    4.1428571, 1, 4.8571429, 2.1428571, 2.4285714, 1.1428571, 
    1.4285714, 2.1428571, 1.4285714, 1.4285714, 2.7142857, 1.5714286, 
    3.4285714, 2.5714286, 5.8571429, 1.5714286, 1.1428571, 2.2857143, 
    1.8571429, 1.5714286, 2, 1.4285714, 3.7142857, 1.5714286, 
    2.5714286, 5, 2.8571429, 5.1428571, 1.5714286, 3.5714286, 
    3.4285714, 0.57142857, 1.8571429, 2.4285714, 2.7142857, 1, 
    2.2857143, 2.4285714, 1.8571429, 3, 2.8571429, 0.57142857, 
    1.1428571, 2.1428571, 2.8571429, 0.28571429, 1.8571429, 4.7142857, 
    3.5714286, 3.4285714, 1.1428571, 1.4285714, 1.5714286, 3.2857143, 
    1.4285714, 2.5714286, 2.4285714, 2.5714286, 1.7142857, 1.8571429, 
    0.71428571, 1.8571429, 2.8571429, 2, 2.4285714, 3.8571429, 
    0.85714286, 2.1428571, 4.4285714, 1, 2.2857143, 0.57142857, 
    0.85714286, 2.1428571, 2.2857143, 2.7142857, 2, 1.7142857, 
    1.4285714, 2.4285714, 2.4285714, 5.5714286, 2.7142857, 3.1428571, 
    4.2857143, 1.8571429, 1.5714286, 1.5714286, 3.7142857, 2.1428571, 
    3, 3.2857143, 2.4285714, 3.8571429, 2.5714286, 1.7142857, 
    2.1428571, 2.7142857, 2.7142857, 3.2857143, 2.7142857, 1.7142857, 
    2.1428571, 5.4285714, 4.2857143, 4.7142857, 4.5714286, 2.7142857, 
    2.7142857, 4.2857143, 2.2857143, 2.7142857, 3.2857143, 1.2857143, 
    2.4285714, 3.7142857, 4.1428571, 3.8571429, 4.7142857, 3.4285714, 
    4.1428571, 1.8571429, 2, 2.4285714, 2.1428571, 1.8571429, 
    1.4285714, 2.4285714, 2, 2.1428571, 2.2857143, 1.8571429, 
    1.1428571, 3.2857143, 1.7142857, 2.7142857, 1.7142857, 1.4285714, 
    4.5714286, 1.5714286, 3.2857143, 1.4285714, 0.85714286, 1.5714286, 
    2, 2, 1.5714286, 2.8571429, 1, 1, 4.2857143, 2, 3.1428571
    ), x7 = c(3.3913043, 3.7826087, 3.2608696, 3, 3.6956522, 
    4.3478261, 4.6956522, 3.3913043, 4.5217391, 4.1304348, 3.7391304, 
    3.6956522, 5.8695652, 5.1304348, 4, 4.0869565, 3.6956522, 
    4, 3.9130435, 3.4782609, 2.6086957, 4.4782609, 3.4782609, 
    5.826087, 4.6956522, 5.7391304, 4.1304348, 2.826087, 5.1304348, 
    4.6521739, 4.826087, 2.0434783, 2.6956522, 5.3913043, 2.7826087, 
    3.1304348, 3.826087, 4.0869565, 5.5217391, 3.2173913, 4.9130435, 
    2.826087, 3.9565217, 3.9565217, 5.3913043, 4.826087, 3.3478261, 
    6.1304348, 5.6521739, 2.5652174, 2.3478261, 3.6521739, 3.2608696, 
    3.4782609, 4.173913, 4.0434783, 4.173913, 3.4347826, 3.3913043, 
    3.5217391, 5.2608696, 4.9130435, 2.6521739, 5.5217391, 3.3043478, 
    5.6956522, 3.6086957, 3.8695652, 6.826087, 4.7391304, 3.6086957, 
    3.7391304, 5.2608696, 3.4782609, 3.4782609, 3.1304348, 5.6521739, 
    5.6956522, 5.5652174, 4.6956522, 5.8695652, 5.1304348, 5.3478261, 
    5.7826087, 4.9565217, 4.6086957, 4.0869565, 5.5217391, 3.5652174, 
    4.173913, 6.6521739, 5.3913043, 3.5652174, 3.6086957, 4.1304348, 
    3.5652174, 5.5217391, 5.1304348, 5.5652174, 4.9130435, 4.2608696, 
    4.5217391, 5.8695652, 3.826087, 3, 6.3478261, 7.4347826, 
    4.173913, 5.6956522, 4.4782609, 3.2608696, 2.8695652, 4.5652174, 
    4.6956522, 3.5652174, 4.826087, 5.3043478, 5.5652174, 3.6956522, 
    4.0869565, 5.826087, 4.6086957, 3.7391304, 3.6521739, 5, 
    4, 5.1304348, 4.9130435, 3.3043478, 4.5217391, 4.5652174, 
    7.2608696, 4.9130435, 4.6956522, 3.4347826, 4.3913043, 3.3478261, 
    4.4347826, 6.2608696, 6.4347826, 6.0434783, 3.3043478, 3.826087, 
    5.3478261, 2.3913043, 5.6086957, 6.9565217, 4.5217391, 3.5652174, 
    5.1304348, 5.6521739, 5.7826087, 5.3913043, 5.3913043, 4.6956522, 
    3.6086957, 3, 2.826087, 2.173913, 4.9565217, 4.8695652, 4.0869565, 
    5.6086957, 4.173913, 4.4782609, 3.8695652, 3.826087, 4.4782609, 
    3.6086957, 4.3043478, 2.1304348, 2.826087, 2.8695652, 3.1304348, 
    4.1304348, 3.5652174, 4.6086957, 3.826087, 4.8695652, 5.4782609, 
    2.9565217, 3.2173913, 4.173913, 2.3913043, 3.5217391, 2.2173913, 
    2.2608696, 4.6956522, 3.5217391, 2.173913, 4.3478261, 2.4347826, 
    3.5217391, 1.3043478, 4.0434783, 4, 4.1304348, 2.5217391, 
    2.826087, 2.6521739, 3.5652174, 2.6956522, 2.6521739, 3.0869565, 
    2.6521739, 3.6956522, 2.7826087, 4.1304348, 2, 3.7391304, 
    3.826087, 3.8695652, 4.3478261, 3.4782609, 3.173913, 3.4782609, 
    5.2173913, 2.9130435, 4.6086957, 4.3913043, 1.8695652, 3.173913, 
    3.173913, 4.3913043, 5.3913043, 3.9130435, 3.8695652, 5.1304348, 
    2.9565217, 3.5217391, 2.9565217, 3.826087, 2.9565217, 2.4347826, 
    3.3043478, 5.6521739, 3.6521739, 4.7391304, 4.7391304, 6.4782609, 
    4.8695652, 4.4782609, 5.826087, 3.6956522, 4, 4.7826087, 
    3.6521739, 4, 5.7391304, 5.7826087, 6.0434783, 5.7826087, 
    4.173913, 5.1304348, 3.4782609, 3.3913043, 4.4347826, 5, 
    4.1304348, 2.9565217, 3.7826087, 4.3478261, 4.826087, 3.3913043, 
    5.0869565, 4.173913, 6.3043478, 4.3043478, 4.2173913, 5, 
    4.6086957, 3, 5.8695652, 3.6956522, 4.7391304, 4, 3.3913043, 
    3.5652174, 4.6086957, 3.6521739, 3.4782609, 2.3913043, 3.3478261, 
    2.7826087, 4.2608696, 3.4782609, 3.3478261, 5.8695652, 5.2173913, 
    2.4347826, 5.826087, 4.173913, 5.4782609, 3.3913043, 4.173913, 
    3.0434783, 5.0869565, 4.6086957, 4, 5.0869565, 4.0869565), 
    x8 = c(5.75, 6.25, 3.9, 5.3, 6.3, 6.65, 6.2, 5.15, 4.65, 
    4.55, 5.7, 5.15, 5.2, 4.7, 4.35, 3.8, 6.65, 5.25, 4.85, 5.35, 
    4.6, 5.45, 4.6, 5.3, 4.6, 6.25, 5.1, 5.55, 5.85, 4.85, 6.95, 
    3.65, 4.3, 4.35, 5.2, 3.75, 4, 3.5, 5.45, 4.5, 5.1, 5.3, 
    4.75, 5.6, 5, 5, 6.35, 8, 5.9, 4.8, 5.05, 5.15, 4.2, 5.1, 
    4.8, 5.7, 5.25, 5.8, 4.55, 6.15, 6.2, 5.35, 3.85, 5.45, 4.5, 
    5.4, 5.75, 6.1, 5.7, 5.95, 5.5, 5.75, 7.35, 4.6, 5.7, 5.75, 
    5.7, 4, 7.35, 5.15, 6.45, 5.75, 5.2, 5.75, 4.85, 6.85, 5.4, 
    4.55, 5.55, 5.95, 7.5, 7.8, 6.4, 4.8, 5.35, 3.6, 5.85, 5.55, 
    6.1, 5.15, 5.3, 4.4, 6.25, 4.85, 6.2, 6.5, 5.7, 6.8, 6.4, 
    4.15, 3.9, 6, 5.35, 4.3, 3.95, 5.85, 6.85, 6.6, 5.2, 5.55, 
    6.4, 6.4, 7.6, 5.35, 6.9, 6.95, 5.65, 5.25, 5.1, 6.25, 7.8, 
    6.35, 6, 5.25, 6, 5.85, 5.1, 5.15, 6.55, 8.3, 5.25, 5.25, 
    7.1, 5.75, 5.6, 4.9, 6.25, 5, 6.3, 4.75, 7.55, 7.9, 7.5, 
    6.15, 5.6, 6.15, 4.1, 4.9, 4.3, 5.15, 6.1, 5.65, 6.95, 4.75, 
    5.7, 5.05, 5.35, 6.8, 5.4, 4.35, 4.2, 4, 5.65, 5.2, 5.5, 
    5.15, 4, 6.05, 5.75, 10, 5.8, 5.9, 6.05, 5.9, 6.4, 4.6, 4.7, 
    5.65, 5.8, 3.6, 7.2, 6.5, 4.8, 3.05, 5.55, 5.4, 4.6, 4.55, 
    4.2, 5, 5.2, 4.15, 3.85, 4.7, 3.5, 6.4, 3.7, 6.4, 3.6, 4.95, 
    5.7, 6.05, 6.05, 5.6, 4.2, 5.05, 5.45, 4.4, 6.35, 5.3, 5, 
    3.65, 5.05, 5.6, 5.95, 6.3, 5.8, 5.8, 4.1, 5.2, 4.85, 5.45, 
    4.55, 3.75, 5.7, 5.25, 6.35, 5.55, 7.15, 7.8, 6.3, 4.9, 5.1, 
    4.95, 4.75, 6.75, 6.6, 6.25, 5.9, 5.55, 5.5, 8.05, 6.1, 5.6, 
    4.75, 5.05, 5.65, 6.8, 5.95, 4, 4.65, 9.1, 6.25, 5.15, 5.4, 
    5.65, 5.85, 5.4, 6, 6.45, 5.3, 6.5, 7.1, 5.45, 7, 4.05, 4.45, 
    5.4, 7.15, 6.3, 5.85, 4, 4.7, 4.7, 6.6, 5.25, 5.95, 6.3, 
    6.55, 5.75, 5.5, 5.75, 6, 5.15, 4.85, 4.25, 5.6, 6.05, 6, 
    6.2, 6.95), x9 = c(6.3611111, 7.9166667, 4.4166667, 4.8611111, 
    5.9166667, 7.5, 4.8611111, 3.6666667, 7.3611111, 4.3611111, 
    4.3055556, 4.1388889, 5.8611111, 4.4444444, 5.8611111, 5.1388889, 
    5.25, 5.4444444, 5.75, 4.9166667, 5.3888889, 7, 5, 6.7777778, 
    4.1388889, 4.3333333, 4.5277778, 4.4166667, 8.6111111, 5.4444444, 
    5.9722222, 3.3611111, 4.8055556, 5.6388889, 4.8333333, 4.9166667, 
    5.3055556, 5.0833333, 5.1111111, 4.8888889, 4.6388889, 4.7777778, 
    2.7777778, 6.6666667, 6.8611111, 5, 6.2777778, 5.4444444, 
    6.0555556, 5.5277778, 5.5, 4.7777778, 5.3888889, 4.1944444, 
    4.4166667, 5.5555556, 5.6388889, 4.75, 4.8333333, 3.9444444, 
    6.1388889, 4.7777778, 5.3333333, 5.8333333, 5.0277778, 6.3055556, 
    6.1944444, 4.25, 3.9166667, 5.4166667, 4.6111111, 5.1666667, 
    5.9722222, 4.2777778, 4.5833333, 4.6666667, 6.4722222, 5.6388889, 
    5.75, 5.3333333, 6.0277778, 5.3055556, 5.7777778, 4.9722222, 
    4.5833333, 5.4722222, 5.9722222, 5.1388889, 4.8888889, 6.6666667, 
    5.4444444, 6.1111111, 5.7222222, 3.9444444, 3.7777778, 5.4444444, 
    4.2222222, 7.2222222, 4.6111111, 5.75, 6.25, 6.5833333, 4.1111111, 
    4.8333333, 6.0277778, 6.1666667, 5.1944444, 7, 7.5277778, 
    3.3611111, 4.8611111, 5.4444444, 5.4444444, 6, 6.3333333, 
    5.4166667, 5, 6.4444444, 5.1666667, 5.4444444, 6.8611111, 
    3.3055556, 6.5, 4.7777778, 6.3888889, 5.6666667, 4.9166667, 
    4.9722222, 5.7777778, 6.3055556, 7, 7.1944444, 4.8055556, 
    3.7222222, 6.1666667, 6.1111111, 5.4444444, 4.5555556, 6.8888889, 
    7.0833333, 6.2222222, 5.7222222, 5.7777778, 6.6111111, 5.9722222, 
    3.8611111, 6.3055556, 4.75, 5.4722222, 5.2222222, 6.1666667, 
    6.9444444, 5.4166667, 5.1944444, 4.1388889, 4.6944444, 4.3333333, 
    5.4166667, 6.3333333, 4, 4.4444444, 5.5833333, 9.25, 4.8333333, 
    5.4722222, 4.9444444, 3.8055556, 4.2777778, 5.5833333, 4.0833333, 
    4.75, 3.4722222, 5.1666667, 6.1666667, 4.4722222, 5.6944444, 
    3.2777778, 6.25, 5.1388889, 6.5555556, 6.0833333, 5.3055556, 
    5, 4.9444444, 5.25, 5.0555556, 3.9722222, 5, 4.4166667, 4.5, 
    5.6944444, 5.5, 5.5277778, 3.1111111, 5.1388889, 4.1111111, 
    4.9444444, 4.8055556, 3.8055556, 5.9444444, 6.7777778, 3.9722222, 
    4.4166667, 4.2777778, 3.3333333, 5.6111111, 4.5833333, 3.8055556, 
    3.3611111, 5.9444444, 6.1944444, 6.1666667, 5.7222222, 6.3611111, 
    4.4722222, 5.1388889, 5.6944444, 5, 4.8611111, 4.7777778, 
    4.0277778, 3.6111111, 6.1111111, 3.2222222, 6.1111111, 6.7222222, 
    6.5555556, 7, 4.7222222, 5.8333333, 4.1388889, 5.3055556, 
    5.0277778, 4.9166667, 4.3333333, 6.6944444, 6.3888889, 5.5555556, 
    6.8333333, 6.8611111, 6.3055556, 4.6666667, 6.2222222, 5.25, 
    5.9722222, 5.5277778, 4.0833333, 6.4444444, 5.1944444, 6.5277778, 
    5.5277778, 6.9166667, 5.8888889, 3.6666667, 4.75, 4.9722222, 
    5.8333333, 7.3888889, 6.6666667, 3.4722222, 4.7222222, 6.3055556, 
    5.7222222, 5.5, 6.5833333, 5.7222222, 6.2777778, 5.9722222, 
    7, 5.0833333, 5.1944444, 5.5, 6.25, 6.1111111, 4.9444444, 
    4.1666667, 5.3055556, 5.0555556, 5.5555556, 5.9722222, 6.5277778, 
    4.2777778, 3.75, 5.25, 6.6666667, 5.6944444, 5.4166667, 5.6666667, 
    5.7222222, 5, 6.7777778, 4.8333333, 4.5, 6.3333333, 5.7777778, 
    5.6666667, 5.25, 6.0833333, 7.6111111, 4.3888889, 5.1666667
    )), row.names = c(NA, -301L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You don't do it by hand, unless you want to spend weeks doing arithmetic. I should note, though, that there are several different estimation algorithms, so perhaps there is some way that would take under 40 hours of arithmetic... Also, CFA *is* [a special case of] a structural equation model.

Comment: I understand it takes a long time, but I would like to try doing that by hand. I've struggled so long to understand it so I'm willing to try.

Comment: You might have trouble getting an answer here because I'd be surprised if anyone wants to do this (although hopefully I'll be proved wrong). I think this is a lot like computing a determinant in that I can have a very good understanding of what the determinant of a matrix means and how to theoretically obtain it and manipulate it, but i don't find doing the arithmetic to be enlightening at all (and don't even need to know how). I know I personally would find it more helpful to make my own examples, do simulations, and try it on standard datasets, but still using existing solvers

Comment: You might want to do most but not all of the steps by hand. E.g. you might want a very clear, step by step formulation of the objective function but then leave it to some optimization routine to solve, treating the routine itself as a black box. If this is the case, you may wish to reformulate your post and highlight which steps of the analysis are the most interesting to you and which ones you are willing to skip / leave to an automated routine.